# Can RAM and flash memory be increased after rooting a device?

Tags: internal-storage, ram

How can I increase RAM and flash memory after rooting my Lenovo A269I running Android 2.3.6? After rooting an Android would the RAM and flash memory be increased?

I have not rooted my device yet. But I want to do so.

Comment: Rooting doesn't upgrade your hardware – it neither will give you more RAM, nor more storage. OTOH, it gives you more possibilities to manage existing resources.

Comment: No. Rooting will not change the hardware configuration of your device

Comment: You can better use your device's ROM(internal storage) after rooting.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make your phone "faster", expand storage or upgrade other hardware by rooting your device.

However, you can remove some unwanted system apps when you are rooted, and that should give you some more storage space on your phone.

I suggest you to use [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) to remove some unwanted apps. Be carefull, because if you remove the wrong apps, your device might not boot anymore.

Comment: can also go with the option of custom ROM. Better UI

Answer (score 0):

It can be possible by upgrading Hardware only. But the existing memory can be used wisely by rooting your device.

For example, to get some free space,

- ROM (can remove unwanted System apps)
- RAM (can swap some of your unused app memory from RAM to secondary storage (SD card); try out [RAM Expander](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.swapit.expander.de&hl=en) for instance )

**Note**: we cannot expect the same hardware's performance while swapping
 RAM.

Comment: Note: The RAM you expand to your SD-Card won't be as quick as on your internal storage.

Comment: I agree with you @SuperThomasLab but it help out in critical situations

Answer (score 0):

Well there is an existing workaround - by using an SD Card.

Apps like link2sd (if that doesn't work, try similar apps with good ratings) can actually virtually merge internal storage with SD Card and thus you would be able to install those big apps to the SD Card instead.

Also create another partition in SD Card and use the app Swapper (root) to create a swap partition and thus increase RAM.